# How is possible to read different output from same address in C?

Tags: c, pointers

```
    #include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    const int a = 233;
    int *ptr = &a;
    *ptr = 5234;
    printf("a = %d, *ptr = %d\n", a, *ptr);
    printf("&a = %p, ptr = %p\n", &a, ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

working with pointers, trying to understand the C, but how can I get different values from same adress?

```
a = 233, *ptr = 5234
&a = 0x7ffeecd368a8, ptr = 0x7ffeecd368a8
```

This is the output after using the GCC compilator. The output is the same with Clang as well.

Comment: The program has undefined behavior. You may not change a constant object.

Comment: MSVC warns about `int *ptr = &a;` **initializing different 'const' qualifiers** but produces the "correct/incorrect" output. Perhaps your compiler is making optimisation assumptions based on *undefined behaviour.*

Comment: Turn up your warning level: `warning: initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]`

Comment: You make a promise not to change the value of `a`, so the compiler trusts you  and assumes that `a` has always the value `233`. But then you break that promise. There is no more any guarantees that things works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem:

```
const int a = 233;
int *ptr = &a;
*ptr = 5234;
```

> **6.7.3 Type qualifiers**
> ...
> 6     If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use
> of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined. If an attempt is
> made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue
> with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.<sup>133)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>133) This applies to those objects that behave as if they were defined with qualified types, even if they are
> never actually defined as objects in the program (such as an object at a memory-mapped input/output
> address).</sup>

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

You've told the compiler that `a` is `const` (meaning its value should not change), but then you are trying to change it through `*ptr`.  This is obviously a logic error, but the compiler is not required to handle this situation in any specific way (the behavior is undefined).

The result can quite literally be anything, from a runtime error to corrupted data to unexpected output to behaving exactly as intended.  Whatever result you get doesn't have to be the same from compiler to compiler, or from build to build using the same compiler, or from run to run using the same binary (although it practice that will usually stay the same).

If `a` can written to indirectly, then it shouldn't be declared `const`.  Conversely, if `a` has been declared `const`, then you should not try to update it indirectly.